# Aligning equations while using cases in align environment

Tags: align, cases

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align}
& a+b+c+d+e+f = 15000 & \text{for } a = 1 ... 15  \\
& D_t= 
\begin{cases}
   \text{equation} , & \text{for } t = 1 ... 10 \\
   \text{another equation} , & \text{for } t = 1 ... 10 \\
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
```

This produces the following:
[image]

However, I would like the "for" arguments in cases to be aligned to those in the align environment, which would look something like:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this automatically, rather than using manual spacing. I have tried using arrays, however it didn't seem to solve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: The best choice may depend on whether `equation` and `another equation` are of single-line height, or whether they are tall (include display fractions for example).

Comment: In my case, both equations are of single-line height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\Centerstack` retains a settable but fixed baselineskip.  Thus, using `\Centerstack`s to set both the equations of the case, as well as (separately) the conditions of the case, will insure that their baselineskips are compatible.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
& a+b+c+d+e+f = 15000 && \text{for } a = 1 ... 15  \\
& D_t= \left\{\Centerstack[l]{\text{equation} ,\\ \text{another equation}}\right.&&
   \Centerstack{ \text{for } t = 1 ... 10 \\ \text{for } t = 1 ... 10}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to obtain it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& a+b+c+d+e+f = 15000 &\quad & \text{for } a = 1 ... 15 \\
& D_t=
\begin{cases}
   \text{equation} , \\
   \text{another equation} ,
\end{cases} & & \begin{aligned}
   \text{for } t = 1 ... 10 \\\text{for } t = 1 ... 10
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& a+b+c+d+e+f = 15000 &\quad & \text{for } a = 1 ... 15 \\
& D_t=
\mathrlap{\begin{cases}
   \text{equation} , & \text{for } t = 1 ... 10 \\
   \text{another equation} ,\hspace{1.9em}& \text{for }t = 1 ... 10
\end{cases}}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be easy if we force the left part of each equation to occupy a fixed width, using for example `\makebox[20em][l]{..}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\makebox[20em][l]{$a+b+c+d+e+f = 15000$} \text{for } a = 1 \dots 15 \\
&\makebox[20em][l]{$D_t=\begin{cases}
  \text{equation},  \\
  \text{another equation},
\end{cases}$} \begin{aligned}\text{for } t = 1 \dots 10\\
\text{for } t = 1 \dots 10\end{aligned}             
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]