# Aligning cases and non cases equations

Tags: equations, align, cases, alignment

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        F_1(p) & = 1-\frac{L_0(\underline{c}_1-p)+\mu \underline{c}_1}{\mu p} & \text{ for } p\in \left[\frac{cL_0}{L_0+\mu},c \right] \\
        F_{02}(p) & =\begin{cases} 1-\frac{L_1\left(\frac{cL_0}{L_0+\mu}-p\right)+\mu \frac{cL_0}{L_0+\mu}}{\mu p} & \text{ for } p\in \left[\frac{cL_0}{L_0+\mu},c \right) \\ 
                                   1 & \text{ for } p\geq c,
                     \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

How can I modify the code to achieve alignment at the equals signs and the "for" statements?

[image]

Comment: From just a few days ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427642/aligning-equations-while-using-cases-in-align-environment